# SQL JOINS (How to JOIN values)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Its my first project with SQL so, in fist place on my database I've two tables called Cotizaciones (quote) and Maquinas (Machines).

The problem is when after insert the id values of the machines that has the name (Machines.NameM) on the table "Quote" that has the design idMachine1, idMachine2, idMachine3, etc..... (on some "quotes" I need to use more than one type of "machine").

I tried to called on a datagridview but only shows me the value of the first "idMachine1" and the other "idMachine2", "idMachine3" it repeats the value of the "idMachine1" = "CNC", I know that is problem with my INNER JOIN but I don't know how to "join" the other idvalues because if try with "AND" it won't show values.

This is my sub

```vb
Sub FillData()        
    Dim sql As String

    sql = "SELECT Machines.NameM
           FROM  Quotes INNER JOIN Machines On Quotes.idMachine = Machines.idMachine
                                           AND Quotes.idMachine2 = Machines.idMachine
                                           AND Quotes.idMachine3 = Machines.idMachine
                                           AND Quotes.idMachine4 = Machines.idMachine
                                           AND Quotes.idMachine5 = Machines.idMachine
                                           AND Quotes.idMachine6 = Machines.idMachine"

    Try
        Dim table As New DataTable

        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, GetConnection)
        adapter.Fill(table)
        dgvQuote.DataSource = table
        dgvQuote.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("The following error has been displayed" + ex.ToString + "Quote")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show some sample data and your desired results (as formatted text). And probably  you can simplify the question by running your query in SSMS until its working correctly.

Comment: Table design is incorrect: you should have a `QuoteMachine` linking table, not 6 different columns to join on. Secondly the logic is wrong because your join will only match if *all* the `idMachine` are the same, you want `OR` instead of `AND`. And you should dispose your adapter and connection objects with `Using` blocks

Comment: Either the question is about SQL or it's not. If it is then it has nothing to do with VS or VB. As suggested, you should be testing your SQL query in an appropriate management tool - probably SSMS for SQL Server - until it is working and only then include it in your application code. If it doesn't work, you can post only the SQL code and tag it appropriately. The VB code there is simply making it harder it focus on the actual issue.